Azure Functions no job found (python)
I have developed an azure function app. It is in Python and works perfectly fine. I first developed this in a virtual environment using pyenv on my laptop.
Now, I switched to another laptop, downloaded the function app and set a new virtual environment for this laptop. The function starts fine and the virtual environment works. The packages are installed as far as I can see.
However, when starting the function, I get the error 'No job functions found. Try making your job classes and methods public. If you're using binding extensions (e.g. Azure Storage, ServiceBus, Timers, etc.) make sure you've called the registration method for the extension(s) in your startup code (e.g. builder.AddAzureStorage(), builder.AddServiceBus(), builder.AddTimers(), etc.)'.
I have seen others with similar issues. However, these issues were mostly in the host.json and the local.settings.json.I have not yet been able to find a solution to it, or an error in both of these files. Also, my function_app.py does not throw any errors (possibly because it is not seen...)
The first few lines of my function_app.py, where i added the @app.function_name line as per previous posts:
app = func.FunctionApp(http_auth_level=func.AuthLevel.ANONYMOUS)

@app.function_name("func")
@app.route(route="http_example", auth_level=func.AuthLevel.ANONYMOUS)
def http_trigger(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')

the host.json:
{
"version": "2.0",
"logging": {
"applicationInsights": {
    "samplingSettings": {
    "isEnabled": true,
    "excludedTypes": "Request"
    }
}
},
"extensionBundle": {
    "id": "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle",
    "version": "[3.15.0, 4.0.0)"
    }
}

the local.settings.json:
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
  "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "python",
  "AzureWebJobsFeatureFlags": "EnableWorkerIndexing",
  "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true"
  }
  }

It is good to know that this is another laptop, logged in with an account from another tenant. I am not sure if this may cause an issue.
Thank you in advance.
EDIT:
Screenshot of the folder structure:
folderstructure
launch.json:
{
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "Attach to Python Functions",
        "type": "debugpy",
        "request": "attach",
        "connect": {
            "host": "localhost",
            "port": 9091
        },
        "preLaunchTask": "func: host start"
    }
]

}

Are you getting 'No job functions found error in function app or in local?

@IkhtesamAfrin during the local run.

Can you elaborate  downloading function app, are you creating a python function locally in vs code and executing it?

If yes, then can you try executing your function by navigating to Run -> Start debugging in vs code

I had it on my other laptop. Since it was just a poc i didnt publish it on something like github. I compressed the folder with the function in it, transferred it to my other laptop and extracted it.

Yes it should work if your function contains default Http trigger code in it. Can you try Run -> Start debugging in vs code please?

I just did, and I firstly get an error about the version of python. I assume that this is because i restarted vs code and didnt enter the virtual environment yet. I am however also getting a blank error pop-up that has a 'Open launch.json'
I entered the virtual environment and still get the issue about the python version. Do I have to change this manually in the PATH?

Can you share a screenshot of your folder structure

@IkhtesamAfrin I have added it into the post.

Can you share your code for launch.json file. My launch.json file looks like this

As far as i see, mine is the same (added to the post)

Can you share the exact error which you are getting for python version? Also If you are getting Open launch.json pop up then cancel it and check. Can you try this

@IkhtesamAfrin  If I start the virtual environment, go to run and then start debuggin, a terminal shows up with `Found Python version 3.12.4 (py).
Python 3.6.x to 3.9.x is required for this operation. Please install Python 3.6, 3.7, 3.8, or 3.9 and use a virtual environment to switch to Python 3.6, 3.7, 3.8, or 3.9.

The terminal process "C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -Command func host start" terminated with exit code: 1.
Terminal will be reused by tasks, press any key to close it`


func host start results:`Found Python version 3.8.10 (py).
Azure Functions Core Tools
Core Tools Version:       3.0.5682 Commit hash: N/A  (64-bit)
Function Runtime Version: 3.22.0.0
[2024-06-27T10:53:51.980Z] No job functions found. Try making your job classes and methods public. If you're using binding extensions (e.g. Azure Storage, ServiceBus, Timers, etc.) make sure you've called the registration method for the extension(s) in your startup code (e.g. builder.AddAzureStorage(), builder.AddServiceBus(), builder.AddTimers(), etc.).
For detailed output, run func with --verbose flag.`

I see you are using very old core tool version please update it to latest one. I am using Azure Functions Core Tools Core Tools Version:       4.0.5801 Function Runtime Version: 4.34.1.22669

This probably was the problem. At least I am getting actual code-related errors now (which are, indeed existing errors).


'No job functions found. Try making your job classes and methods public. If you're using binding extensions (e.g. Azure Storage, ServiceBus, Timers, etc.) make sure you've called the registration method for the extension(s) in your startup code (e.g.builder.AddAzureStorage(), builder.AddServiceBus(),builder.AddTimers(), etc.)'.

In order to avoid this error, please follow below steps-

Use correct function code.

import azure.functions as func
import logging

app = func.FunctionApp(http_auth_level=func.AuthLevel.ANONYMOUS)

@app.route(route="http_trigger")
def http_trigger(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')

    name = req.params.get('name')
    if not name:
        try:
            req_body = req.get_json()
        except ValueError:
            pass
        else:
            name = req_body.get('name')

    if name:
        return func.HttpResponse(f"Hello, {name}. This HTTP triggered function executed successfully.")
    else:
        return func.HttpResponse(
             "This HTTP triggered function executed successfully. Pass a name in the query string or in the request body for a personalized response.",
             status_code=200
        )


Ensure to use latest extension in host.json file.

{
  "version": "2.0",
  "logging": {
    "applicationInsights": {
      "samplingSettings": {
        "isEnabled": true,
        "excludedTypes": "Request"
      }
    }
  },
  "extensionBundle": {
    "id": "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle",
    "version": "[4.*, 5.0.0)"
  }
}


It is recommended to use V4 version of Azure Function core Tools. You can either install it using MSI or npm i -g azure-functions-core-tools@4 --unsafe-perm true, refer Azure Functions Core Tools Versions.

Either navigate to Run -> Start debugging in vs code or use func host start command in terminal to execute your function.


You will get the expected response.


My problem was in the fact that I was using an old version of the Functions Core Tools. I have updated this version to version 4 with command:
npm install -g azure-functions-core-tools@4 --unsafe-perm true

Thanks to @Ikhtesam Afrin, who helped me through the comments.
